# swift return key pressed event from subview programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swift4

I am new to swift and creating my app without using storyboard. I created logincontroller and attached loginview to it. When someone complete email and password textfield and from keyboard hit return key, I want to detect event so I can process the user request for login.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class LoginController: UIViewController {

 var loginView: LoginView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
 }

func setupView() {
    let mainView = LoginView(frame: self.view.frame)
    self.loginView = mainView 
    self.view.addSubview(loginView)
}
```

And code for LoginView.swift

```
import UIKit

class LoginView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

func setup() {

    backgroundColor = .white
    let stackView = createStackView(views: [emailTextField,passwordTextField])
    addSubview(stackView)

    //autolayout constraints here

}

let emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField(placeHolder: "Email")
    return tf
}()

let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField(placeHolder: "Password")
    tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
    tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.send
    return tf
}()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to `setup` method

```
func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .white
    let stackView = createStackView(views: [emailTextField,passwordTextField])
    addSubview(stackView)
    emailTextField.delegate = self // This
    passwordTextField.delegate = self // And this
}
```

And then add this below your `LoginView` class

```
extension LoginView: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == passwordTextField {
             passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
             doWhatYouWantTo() // eg. do your login
        } else {
             passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

**Extended Anwer-**

```
class LoginController: UIViewController {
    var loginView: LoginView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        let mainView = LoginView(frame: self.view.frame)
        self.loginView = mainView
        self.loginView.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
    }
}

extension LoginController: LoginViewDelegate{
    func userWantsToLoginWith(userName: String?, password: String?) {
        // Now you have both userName and password here
    }
}

protocol LoginViewDelegate: class {
    func userWantsToLoginWith(userName: String?, password: String?)
}

class LoginView: UIView {
    var delegate: LoginViewDelegate?

    let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField(placeHolder: "Email")
        return tf
    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let tf = UITextField(placeHolder: "Password")
        tf.isSecureTextEntry = true
        tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.send
        return tf
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    func setup() {
        backgroundColor = .white
        let stackView = createStackView(views: [emailTextField, passwordTextField])
        addSubview(stackView)
        //autolayout constraints here
    }
}

extension LoginView: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == passwordTextField {
            passwordTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            delegate?.userWantsToLoginWith(userName: emailTextField.text, password: passwordTextField.text)
        } else {
            passwordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: I will edit answer, then things will be more clear for you.

Comment: perfect it did work. last thing, where is right place to add doWhatYouWantTo() method?

Comment: Right now you can add in `LoginView` but ideally it should be in `LoginController`. I will add some points in answer that might help you.

Comment: In short you should have a delegate in LoginView which should be set to LoginViewController coz controller is the place where any action should take place.

Comment: thanks, cant I just add method inside extension (extension LoginView: UITextFieldDelegate) under textFieldShouldReturn func?

Comment: Try that, if you try more things you will learn more, and there can be many better ways to achieve what you are doing, do upvote if answer worked for you. :)